# Dependency difference between Release & Debug

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to write a rather simple ActiveX using c++ code. Problem is that Release binary has dependency at MFC90.DLL and MSVCR90.DLL which does not apear at the Debug. How to attack this??

Comment: Is your question that you want to be able to debug into the release builds of the MFC dlls or is your question something else?

Comment: Another possibility - do you want to release a debug build of your code, but the DLL variant thing is a problem?

Comment: I think he wants to link statically, to avoid distribution issues since it's an ActiveX.

Answer (score 3):

You can try statically linking MFC and the C++ runtime libraries, which might be desirable because then you won't have to hope users have the VC++ runtime redistributables installed.

Or you can install the VC++ redistributables that will install those shared libraries.

I believe you can also include those missing DLLs in your CAB file (assuming you're installing this as a download via a web browser), but you might as well try to statically link if you're going to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Debug builds can still use release DLLs/libs, it just means you can't step into the code for those parts when debugging.

It's perfectly normal, unless I misunderstood the question?